# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService') in typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am trybing to call userService class in usercontroller class:

UserService

```
    class UserService {
        public findAll(){
            return await UserRepository.find({})
        }
    }
    
    export default UserService;
```

UserController:

```
import { UserRepository } from "../repositories/userRepository"
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"
import UserService from "../services/userService"


class UserController {
   public userService = new UserService()
    async findAllUsers(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const users = this.userService.findAll()
        response.json(users)
    }


}
export default UserController
```

UserRoute:

```
class UserRoute implements Routes {
    public path = '/users';
    public router = Router()
    public userController = new UserController()
    constructor(){
        this.initializeRoutes()
    }
    initializeRoutes() {
        this.router.get(`${this.path}`,this.userController.findAllUsers )
    }
}

export default UserRoute
```

But I always get the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Probably because of the context. findAllUsers function inside initiateRouters has run with the context of this.router instead of this.userController.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you @ToanQuocHo

Comment: In JavaScript, whenever you run a function, there is a context where your function will be run on. It's like a space of variables where your function can reference to. So in this case, findAllUsers is not running in the right context, try this Alvanxl: this.userController.findAllUsers.bind(this.userController)

Comment: You're welcome Alvanxl. You can also find some more information about bind,call,apply methods in JS, like when to use and why we need it